# How to update documents with map/reduce functions?

Tags: couchdb

I am searching for a way to update and persist documents from within the reduce function of a custom design document. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Comment: Why all those tags? Is it a `javascript` problem? Is it a general `couchdb` problem? Is it a problem specific to `couchdb-2.0`? A problem that only is relevant for all `2.x` versions of couchdb? Or is it just relevant for the `3.x` branch?

Comment: Should be relevant for all tags.

Answer (score 0):

> I am searching for a way to update and persist documents from within the reduce function of a custom design document. Is it possible?

No. It is not possible.